# I want to pull data into a Visualforce stacked bar chart using an Apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts

Every example I've seen is of Visualforce stacked bar charts with the data hard-coded in the Apex controller, similar to https://hub.appirio.com/tech-blog/building-dynamic-stacking-bar-charts-in-visualforce.

If I have 3 parent records with up to 10 child records, I want to display 3 stacked bars. The below code display as a simple bar chart, not stacked:

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class PFResidentialSchoolExpendController {
    public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() {
        List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();
        List<Residential_School_Expenditure_Details__c> queryResults =
            [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Residential_School_Expenditure_Phase__c, Expenditure_Type__c,
                              Expected_Expenditure__c FROM Phase_wise_Expenditure_Details__r)
            FROM Residential_School_Expenditure_Details__c
            ORDER BY Name DESC];
        if(queryResults.size() > 0) {
            for(Residential_School_Expenditure_Details__c r : queryResults) {
                for(Phase_wise_Expenditure_Details__c p : r.Phase_wise_Expenditure_Details__r) {
                    data.add(new PieWedgeData(r.Name,p.Expected_Expenditure__c));
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
        else {
            System.debug('No expenditures found.');
            return null;
        }
    }
    public class PieWedgeData {
        public String name1 {get; set;}
        public Decimal data1 {get; set;}
        }
    }
}
```

**Visualforce:**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
           controller="PFResidentialSchoolExpendController" title="Residential School Expenditures">
    <apex:stylesheet value="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"/>
    <style>
        .widget-title {
            font-size: 50px;
            line-height: 46px;
            font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            margin-bottom: 24px;
            display: block;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: #FFFFFF
        }
    
        .widget-text {
            font-size: 17px;
            line-height: 26px;
            font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
        }
    </style><br/>
    <apex:chart height="300" width="800" data="{!pieData}" colorSet="#405395, #E5763E, #009345">
        <apex:axis type="Category" position="left" fields="name1" title="Phase"/>
        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="bottom" fields="data1"
                   title="Expenditures"/>
        <apex:barSeries orientation="horizontal" axis="bottom" xField="data1" yField="name1"
                        stacked="true"
                        title="Agricultural Development,Construction,Demolition,Earthwork,Furniture/Fixture/Equipment,Inspection,Land,Operations,Other,Sitework"/>
        <apex:legend position="right"/>
    </apex:chart><br/>
</apex:page>
```